# Inconsistent datatypes in Oracle ODP.Net vs Microsoft .Net provider for Oracle - .Net 3.5

Tags: .net, oracle, ado.net

I have a legacy .Net 3.5 application (500,000 lines of executable code, so quite large) that supports Oracle and Sql Server and uses the now deprecated Microsoft .Net provider for Oracle (as supplied with the .Net framework). We have been asked to substitute the Oracle ODP.Net provider, but I am having huge problems with incompatible datatypes.

For example, we have database columns of number(10,0) to represent integers (int32), and number(5,0) to represent small integers (16bit). These columns were returned by ADO.Net using the MS .Net provider as int32 and int16 respectively. However, with the Oracle ODP.Net provider ADO.Net returns them as int64 and int32 respectively, which because most of the code is DBMS-neutral and has to work with Sql Server as well, causes serious casting problems in the code.

Is there a way of forcing the ODP.Net provider to work the same way as the Microsoft one in this respect?

If not, what is the recommended 'fix' for this incompatibility?

TIA

Comment: By default column values should be of datatype `object`. Can you provide a pice of code showing your problem. A `NUMBER(5,0)` can store nubmers up to 99999, which does not fit into `int16`, resp. `short`. So, you may have problems with "non-matching" data types anyway.

Comment: ADO providers from MS and Oracle are not compatibel to each other. For example, method `OracleParameterCollection.AddWithValue` exists only in Microsoft but not in Oracle.